# Stripe Elements shipping info collection

Tags: stripe-payments

How do I collect shipping info using Stripe Elements? I'm using react and can't seem to figure out how to get a form with shipping info. I've managed to get a card element take payment using payment intents, but I don't see any examples of making a shipping form to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use Elements to collect shipping info, you'd use your own HTML form to do that.

Then when you're ready to confirm the payment you'd pass in that shipping info to Stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-shipping